# Error with knitr on texmaker

Tags: r, knitr, texmaker

I am trying for the first time to get knitr running on texmaker, I followed [this documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/) and I am on Windows 7. However, when I compile, I get the following error stack:

```
Process started

Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : cannot open the connection Calls: <Anonymous> -> knit -> readLines

In addition: Warning message: In readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : cannot open file 'try_easy.Rnw': No such file or directory

Execution halted

Process exited with error(s)
```

I tried to google it, but only found references to linux/unix, which were not helpful for my case. Following is my short test document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}

<<a>>=
x=rnorm(100)
<<b>>=
<<a>>
mean(x)
@

\end{document}
```

It's my first time on stackoverflow, so please tell me if you need more information or I did something wrong. Thank you very much.

**Update**
Hello everyone,

I managed to find out my mistake. For the sake of future google-searchers, I had saved the file as a `.tex`  instead as `.rnw`. Saving as `rnw` solved it. Since I cannot answer my own questions, I edit it here.

Comment: Your chunk is strange. I would remove `<<b>>=
<<a>>`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I removed '<<b>>=<<a>>' and the error message did not change.

Comment: I would like to recommend you RStudio to work with LaTeX, R, and knitr. I use both Texmaker and RStudio. But Texmaker only, if I produce LaTeX only files. From my point of view RStudio is much more convenient for *.Rnw-files. Have a look: http://www.rstudio.com/ The recent version has some great changes and you can also use version control with git or subversion.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the file is saved as a `.tex` instead of a `.Rnw`, as the compiler does not know that he should "knitr-compile" files that have the `.tex` handle, unless you specifically set him up like that.